# Good open source MariaDB front-end

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, mariadb

I have been using MySQL Workbench to manage MySQL DBs. Recently, I had to work with MariaDB, but found that MySQL Workbench is not fully compatible with MariaDB 10. I am currently using MyCli, a linux console tool. It works quite well, but I miss the functionality of MySQL Workbench. I looked at the following page, but most of the tools are either lackluster or not free:

[MariaDB Frontends and Clients](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/graphical-and-enhanced-clients/)

Can anyone recommend a better tool which is completely free, runs natively on linux and has good functionality? I am running Linux Mint 18.

Comment: At some point you need to ween yourself from frontends and write SQL directly.

Comment: I can see you have A LOT of experience with SQL so I will follow your advice. But GUI tools provide a lot of extra features such as relationship diagrams, backup and migration tools, etc. Would these / or some of these features be available using bash tools and cli applications / scripts? I have been working with MS SQL since 2011 but always relied on GUI tools so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: UIs are good for casual probing of the database.  But they should not be depended on for application coding.

Comment: Check out phpmyadmin.  Meanwhile, what issues have you encountered with Workbench and MariaDB?

Comment: It works ok but I am greeted with warning(s) each time I connect to a MariaDB database. I will stick to a console tool. But, I consider this as closed as it is off-topic. Sorry about this admins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after taking Rick James' comment into consideration and doing some more research, I have concluded that MyCli is the only viable option to my requirements stated in my question. If however you are using windows and you want to use a GUI tool, I would highly recommend SQLyog.